# Laravel: Error in Passing a multidimensional array from controller to view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Route File:-

```
Route::get('/',function()
{
 $menuitem = Menuitem::all(); 
 return VIEW::make('index',$menuitem); 
});
```

index.blade.php:-

```
@foreach($menuitem as $item)
 {{$item['item_link']}} 
@endforeach
```

I am getting an error `Undefined variable $menuitem` in `index.blade.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Route::get('/',function()
{
    $menuitem = Menuitem::all(); 
    return View::make('index')->with('menuItem', $menuItem); 
}
```

Comment: Finally I can access array in view . Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

`View::make` accepts an array for the second parameter.

```
public View make(string $view, array $data = array(), array $mergeData = array())
```

So it should be:

```
Route::get('/',function()
{
  $menuitem = Menuitem::all();

  $data = array(
            'menuitemKey' => $menuitem
          );

  return View::make('index', $data); 
}
```

Then you can access it like:

```
@foreach($menuitemKey as $item)
  {{$item['item_link']}} 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
'Route('/',function(){
$myarray = Menuitem::all();
return View::make('myview')->with('data',$myarray);
})'
```

myview.blade.php

```
'@for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data),$i++)
 {{$data[$i]['item']}}
  @endfor'
```